# how to put 3 in a list by using .each

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, each

I have this code

```
<ul id="mycarousel-1" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
  <% @portfolios.each_slice(3) do |f| %> 
    <li><% @portfolios.each do |f| %> 
     <%= link_to image_tag(f.image.url(:medium)), image_path(f.image.url()),class: "plus"  %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

How can I put each 3 image in a one list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul id="mycarousel-1" class="jcarousel-skin-tango">
  <% @portfolios.each_slice(3) do |slice| %> 
    <li>
       <% slice.each do |portfolio| %> 
         <%= link_to image_tag(portfolio.image.url(:medium)), image_path(portfolio.image.url), class: "plus"  %>
       <% end %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```